# Parse nested json into ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have sample json structured as,

```
{ key : { "data1":data1, "data2":data2 }}
```

I want it to be parsed into the 'data',

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'url',
    data: <--- here ,
    success: function() { 
        *****
    }
});
```

How do I do it?

Comment: (`var ajaxData = { key : [ "data1":data1, "data2":data2 ]};` && `data: ajaxData`) || `data: { key : [ "data1":data1, "data2":data2 ]}`

Comment: @AlonEitan thanks...

Comment: that structure is invalid ...arrays don't have properties...objects do

Comment: @charlietfl Oh right!  I hope it's just the OP forgot to include a pair of curly brackets or two in the question

Comment: oh yes, curly braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use JSON.stringify

```
var data= { "key" : {"data1":"data1", "data2":"data2" }};
new Request.JSON({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    onSuccess: function(res) {
        document.write(data.key.data1);
        console.log(data.key.data1);
    }
}).send();
```

Here is the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dK5DL/87/

Comment: thanks for the solution. i had the similar approach. my intension was to assign the data to a key, it just makes it lot easier to retrieve the data later on. Thanks a ton.